# How to stop one process detecting another is running

Tags: windows-7, process, task-manager

I have an application (**Utility.exe**) that refuses to perform certain operations if it detects another process (**Target.exe**) is running. I am not certain of the detection method that it uses. It may be a periodic poll for a list of processes, and if a process name matches certain criteria then the application locks down specific features.

- If I rename **Target.exe** >> **FooBar.exe** and launch **FooBar.exe** then both tools work concurrently (ie the features of **Utility.exe** don't lock down)
- However, **Target.exe** periodically updates from a remote location and relaunches a process with the filename **Target.exe** at which point **Utility.exe** ceases to function — this hack doesn't not fully solve my issue.
- I have no control over the source code of **Target.exe** or **Utility.exe**

I want to run both applications concurrently.

Is there a way I can prevent **Utility.exe** from detecting **Target.exe**, thus removing the need to rename this process?

Comment: In windows, all users are capable of seeing all processes at least by filename, though other info will be suppressed, so other than a rootkit, it will be difficult to do it the way you suggest. I'd probably try using a filesystem watcher of some kind to watch for the file creation and to rename it then.

Comment: @FrankThomas is right. As a last resort, you could try hack **Target.exe** with a hex-editor so that, when it auto-updates, it goes with the name **Marget.exe**, or whatever - same number of characters of course.

Answer (score 1):

Run foobar.exe and make a batch file script as follows:

```
@echo off
:loop
taskkill /PID "target.exe"
goto loop
```

run this batch script. The process target.exe will get terminated as soon as it is initiated.
Or, you could find where the new target.exe file is copied by the remote server and designate that folder as read-only.

Comment: Do not forget to run the code as administrator.

Comment: You should update your answer to include that information if it does not work without doing so